# Loop Copy Paste at specific interval

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm a beginner and trying to run a vba which does this:

- copy a formula from a starting point (cell B6)
- paste this formula every 18 rows down on the same column
- repeat the process until the cell says "End of Report"

I have the following code and I can't make it run properly (inherited formula only from an existing report):

```
'(a) to set the formula at starting point: 
        Windows("RAVEN MNL adj.xlsm").Activate
        Range("B6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RIGHT(RC[-1],7))"

'(b) to copy paste in loop 
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ii As Long
        Dim strLastCell As Long
        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = Range("B:B").Cells

        strLastCell = rng.Find(what:="End of Report", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        ii = i + 18
        i = ActiveCell.Select

        For ii = i To strLastCell
        Range("B6").Copy
        Range("B" & ii).Paste
        Next ii
        End Sub
```

The error seems to be at the "strLastCell" bit. Can you help?

Comment: `i` is a Long. You can't assign `ActiveCell.Select` to a Long variable. You say you want to write every 18 rows, then you need to increment ii by 18 with `For ii = i To strLastCell step 18`

Answer (score 0):

If you want same formula as in B6 cell to be placed in every 18th cell from B6 until the 'End of Report' cell use this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim strLastCell As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("B:B").Cells

    strLastCell = rng.Find(what:="End of Report", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).ROW

    For ii = 6 To strLastCell Step 18
        Range("B" & ii).FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RIGHT(RC[-1],7))"
    Next ii

End Sub
```